# Why are my images blurry on large devices even though I provide high quality png Drawables?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-screen-support

My game's images (especially the backgrounds) are noticeably blurry when I test on my IdeaTab S6000 (1280 x 800, hdpi) and I'm trying to figure out why. I provide my drawables as `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, and `xxxhdpi` (because newer devices have higher density). So the resources I provide are of higher quality than the device needs, yet the background appears to have been converted and not with a great-quality conversion. I even tried providing only xxxhdpi and that actually made it worse.

So is Android just really bad at down-scaling large drawables and I need to provide hdpi, or am I doing something else wrong to make the pictures blurry?

Comment: "So is Android just really bad at down-scaling large drawables and I need to provide hdpi?" Yes.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, thanks. I provided hdpi resources and the quality has improved. It's not quite where I'd like it to be and I'm not sure why, but it definitely helped.

Comment: By the way, if you're using the Canvas for your game, you shouldn't be using Drawables in the first place. I'm just saying that because your game has to be pretty basic if it's only using the standard Android layout components.